# JOIN query not producing the correct results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query where I am trying to join my `profile_img` and `users` table to match the id's in the `friends` table (friend_one or friend_two) in oder to get their profile image or user information.

As of now, I do not get any errors...just not the correct results I am looking for. There should be two results that show relation to `:profile_user`... 5 and 2, which would also give ocean and lake for their profile_img.

The parameter `:profile_user` is equal to 1. `:total_status` = 2.

I am not sure if my `ON` clauses are throwing this off or not. I am not sure how to make `u.id =` to both the `friend_one` or `friend_two`.

Does anyone see why this isn't working?

[Here is a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/adc22)

```
SELECT f.*, u.*, p.*, IFNULL(p.img, 'profile_images/default.jpg') AS img
        FROM friends f
        JOIN
            users u
            ON u.id = (f.friend_one or f.friend_two)
        LEFT JOIN
            profile_img p
            ON p.user_id = f.friend_one or f.friend_two and p.id = (select max(p2.id) from profile_img p2 where p2.user_id = p.user_id)     
        WHERE (friend_one = :profile_user or friend_two = :profile_user)
        AND status = :total_status
```

Full code, which is showing 0 results.

```
$friend_status = 2;
    $friend_sql = "
        SELECT f.*, u.*, p.*, IFNULL(p.img, 'profile_images/default.jpg') AS img
        FROM friends f
        JOIN
            users u
            ON u.id = (f.friend_one or f.friend_two)
        LEFT JOIN
            profile_img p
            ON p.user_id = f.friend_one or f.friend_two and p.id = (select max(p2.id) from profile_img p2 where p2.user_id = p.user_id)     
        WHERE (friend_one = :profile_user or friend_two = :profile_user)
        AND status = :total_status
    ";
    $friend_stmt = $con->prepare($friend_sql);
    $friend_stmt->execute(array(':profile_user' => $profile_user, ':total_status' => $friend_status));
    $friend_total_rows = $friend_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $count_total_friend = $friend_stmt->rowCount();
?>  
        <div id="friend-list-container">
            <div id="friend-list-count">Friends <span class="light-gray"><?php echo $count_total_friend; ?></span></div>
            <div id="friend-list-image-container">
<?php
    foreach ($friend_total_rows as $friend_total_row) {
        $friend_1           = $friend_total_row['friend_one'];
        $friend_2           = $friend_total_row['friend_two'];
        $friend_img         = $friend_total_row['img'];
        $friend_username    = $friend_total_row['username'];
        if($friend_1 !== $profile_user) {
            echo $friend_1;
            echo $friend_img;
            echo $friend_username;
        }
        if($friend_2 !== $profile_user) {
            echo $friend_2;
            echo $friend_img;
            echo $friend_username;
        }
    }
```

Comment: having an OR in the join is very strange -- can you describe this data model? I think you want two joins but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Hogan I am looking to find the `u.id` for both the `friend_one` and `friend_two`.

Comment: @Hogan The friends table is a relation table. `friend_one` sent a friend request, `friend_two` is the person they sent it to, `status` if it equals 2 means they are friends. So, what I am trying to do is show how many friends the user has and then display their friend's user info and picture.

Comment: you can't join on both this breaks relational data model and is why it is not working. -- I'll post what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after I posted the below I realized mysql does not support cte -- here a version without:

```
SELECT f.*,
       u1.*,
       u2.*,
       p1.*,
       p2.*,
       IFNULL(p1.img, 'profile_images/default.jpg') AS img1,
       IFNULL(p2.img, 'profile_images/default.jpg') AS img2
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON u1.id = f.friend_one 
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = f.friend_two
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, max(id) as mid
  FROM profile_img
  GROUP BY user_id
) max1 ON u1.user_id = max1.user_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, max(id) as mid
  FROM profile_img
  GROUP BY user_id
) max2 ON u2.user_id = max2.user_id
LEFT JOIN profile_img p1 ON p1.user_id = f.friend_one and p1.id = max1.mid
LEFT JOIN profile_img p2 ON p2.user_id = f.friend_two and p2.id = max2.mid
WHERE (friend_one = :profile_user or friend_two = :profile_user)
        AND status = :total_status
```

---

```
WITH maxImage AS
(
  SELECT user_id, max(id) as mid
  FROM profile_img
  GROUP BY user_id
)
SELECT f.*,
       u1.*,
       u2.*,
       p1.*,
       p2.*,
       IFNULL(p1.img, 'profile_images/default.jpg') AS img1,
       IFNULL(p2.img, 'profile_images/default.jpg') AS img2
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON u1.id = f.friend_one 
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = f.friend_two
LEFT JOIN maxImage max1 ON u1.user_id = max1.user_id
LEFT JOIN maxImage max2 ON u2.user_id = max2.user_id
LEFT JOIN profile_img p1 ON p1.user_id = f.friend_one and p1.id = max1.mid
LEFT JOIN profile_img p2 ON p2.user_id = f.friend_two and p2.id = max2.mid
WHERE (friend_one = :profile_user or friend_two = :profile_user)
        AND status = :total_status
```

Comment: `maxImage` is not a table in my database.

Comment: @Paul -- that is called a CTE - it lets you define a table "in line".   Your platform (mysql) does not support it which is why I put the other version above the line.

Comment: The table above the line gives this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pfarley1_fh.maxImage' doesn't exist' in `...which it looks to pointing at my execute array line, `PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} `  ... `$friend_stmt->execute(array(':profile_user' => $profile_user, ':total_status' => $friend_status));` Why would this affect my execute line?

Comment: @Paul -- I'm sorry -- I totally messed up when I created the first query and substituted in the wrong place.  I've edited the code and hopefully fixed it.

Comment: I tried the top choice in your answer and it gives this error - not sure what it would be... `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'maxImage AS ( SELECT user_id, max(id) as mid FROM profile_img GROUP BY use' at line 1' in`

Comment: Try newest had typo

Comment: Thanks. I changed the u1.user_id to u1.id and same for u2. That seemed to help, but for some reason the looped results are only outputting the `:profile_user` data and not the other user associated with them. For instance, if the profile_user is id 1, he should be associated with user 2 and 5 and their data should be displaying as well. See the friend table in the fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/adc22

Comment: I believe the error is in how I am outputting it. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an "id" column in your friend table that is the same as the column "id" of your user table, i think you should try this

```
ON u.id = f.id
```

instead of

```
ON u.id = (f.friend_one or f.friend_two)
```

Comment: The id column in the friends table is just an id, not the actual users id...that is what friend_one and two are.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data in the mentioned SQL Fiddle. Below is the query that i think will help

```
select 
res1.firstname as FriendOneFirstName,
res1.lastname as FriendOneLastName,
res1.img as FriendOneImage,
user1.firstname as FriendTwoFirstName,
user1.lastname as FriendTwoLastName,
pf1.img as FirendTwoProfileImage
from
(select usr.id,usr.firstname,usr.lastname,pf.img,frds.friend_two 
 from users usr 
 inner join friends frds on usr.id=frds.friend_one
 inner join profile_img pf on usr.id = pf.user_id
 ) as res1
inner join users user1 on user1.id=res1.friend_two
inner join profile_img pf1 on user1.id=pf1.user_id
order by user1.id;
```